# How do I call a property from inside a javascript closure

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript closure and inside the method `getresult()`.  I want to call a property in the object `quo`.

```
var quo = function (test) {
        talk: function () {
            return 'yes';
        }
        return {
            getresult: function () {
                return quo.talk();
            }
        }
    }
var myQuo = quo('hi');
document.write(myQuo.getresult());
```

From inside `getresult()`, how can I call the property `talk`?

Answer (score 4):

your syntax is wrong, and you cant call talk from the quo reference, talk is not accessible from the outside, if you wanna call talk from quo then you have to add a reference to it in your returned object

```
var quo = function (test) {
    function talk() {
        return 'yes';
    }
    return {
        getresult: function () {
            return talk();
        },
        talk: talk
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`quo` is no object, but a simple function, and has no properties (technically, it could have, but that does not apply here).

```
var quo = function(test) {
     function talk() {
          return 'yes';
     }
     /* OR:
     var talk = function() {
          return 'yes';
     }; */

     return {
         getresult: function() {
             // in here, "quo" references the closure function.
             // "talk" references the local (function) variable of that "quo" function
             return talk();
         }
     }
}
var myQuo = quo('hi');

myQuo.getresult(); // "yes"
```

If you want to get a property "`talk`" on the `myQuo` object, you would need to use this:

```
var quo = function(test) {
    return {
        talk: function() {
             return 'yes';
        },
        getresult: function() {
             // in here, "quo" references the closure.
             // "this" references current context object,
             // which would be the the object we just return (and assign to "myQuo")
             return this.talk();
        }
    };
}
var myQuo = quo('hi');

myQuo.getresult(); // "yes"
```

Read more on the [`this` keyword at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: Yes this works. Thank you. So now I have closure for talk() and getresult(). They can call each other and be called from out side with myQuo but no one else can access variables in talk() or getresult()

Comment: Only the properties of the object you return a public accessible. All variables declared with the var keyword and functions are scoped to the containing function, from which they can be accessed. You also can access them from other functions inside that one, like the var talk from getresult in the first example.